# Why do registered events disappear when an element is removed from DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

This jQuery 1.3.2 code adds an element to the page, registers a "click" event, then removes and reattaches the element:

```
var button = $('<button>Click me!</button>')
  .click(function(){ alert("Hello") })
  .appendTo('body');

$('body').html('');

button.appendTo('body');
```

The button appears on the page as expected, but clicking on it does nothing. I would like to know why the event handlers were removed from the object.

Note: I am aware of solutions such as `jQuery.live()` or `clone(true)` or using `appendTo` without a removal. What I'm looking for is an *explanation*, not a solution or workaround.

EDIT: I suppose this could be an arbitrary and counter-intuitive design decision of the DOM. An explanation like "Because that's the way section X of specification Y wants it to be" would be fine.

Comment: Can you update the question with the version you are using, or is the same between 1.2.6, 1.3.2 and 1.4 alpha.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you remove an element from the DOM using jQuery, all data (including event handlers) held by jQuery on that element will be destroyed. This is done to avoid memory-leaks.

This isn't a feature (or bug) of the DOM API. It's just jQuery.

Comment: You mean, the IE DOM-and-JS circular reference bug? I see. As a matter of curiosity, how does jQuery detect that the element was removed from the DOM? Is there an event for that?

Comment: jQuery will only "clean" the data if you remove the element using one of jQuery's methods. If you just use `button[0].parentNode.removeChild(button[0])` then jQuery won't know about it.

Comment: Right. So, jQuery's `html()` also runs a removal on all children before setting the new content? Smart. And yet another reason not to use `innerHtml` :)

Comment: This answer was correct at the time it was posted, but 6 days later v1.4.0 was released and added the `.detach()` method, pointed out by John Lenin in his answer. `.detach()` is like `.remove()` but doesn't destroy jQuery data (including handlers). Perhaps you could rewrite your answer to mention `.detach()`, or just flag it for a mod to delete and let John Lenin's answer float to the top? For readers in 2013, this answer is actively misleading.

Answer (score 5):

If you want your registered events to stay on your element use [.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) instead of .remove().  Use it the same way you'd use .remove(), it will keep your events on your element.

Comment: Thanks for pointing in that direction. Exactly the function I needed.